# Not Able To Duck in Counter Strike Condition Zero

Tags: counter-strike-condition-zero

Recently I started to play online on various server, one of them downloaded some maps, sound etc and also **created direct link to server at gateway** of Counter Strike Condition Zero.
Everything was fine that time but when I restarted the game and played my **duck key was stopped responding**.
To get rid of the problem **I restored my key to default** and set again, choosing different key for duck but no luck, even **[image: I uninstalled and reinstalled the whole game about 5 times deleting all related file also used removal software to deleting registry pertaining to it]** but the problem remain each time I played the game.
One more thing that the **direct link to server which was created when i connected to online server didn't disappeared even after uninstalling and reinstalling** the game, I dont know how this happen but I have deleted all the file clear registry.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called autoexec.cfg in your Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike: Condition Zero/cscz/cfg.

I haven't double checked the folder names, so you'll have to correct me on that one.

Edit the file and add the following:

```
bind ctrl +duck
```

This file will be executed everytime the game starts, and thus binding your duck key to the control key every time.

Comment: Uh. The duck key is the one not working here.

Comment: My bad, i'm tired. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to CsCz directory- local disk "C" > Program Files > Counter Strike Condition Zero > czero.
2. Locate File userconfig.cfg.
3. Open it with notepad.
4. Delete whatever written inside it.
5. write- bind "CTRL" "+duck"
6. Save file and exit. Rum cscz.
   You are done. It worked for me.
   Hope You have solved your problem.